# Variable of function value

Tags: java

```
public static void test() {
    int x = 5;

    x = x + 5;
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

Whenever I call function test and print `x` it always gives `5`. What do I need to declare variable `x` so that the first time it prints `5`, then `10`, then `5` etc?

Comment: Can you give an example demonstrating clearly about what you want? and what is `main test()`?

Comment: This code does not compile `public static void main test()`

Comment: My guess would be OP is looking for `static` variables?

Comment: How are you calling `test()` ? any loop ?

Comment: @UnholySheep, he says he needs output as `5` `10` and `5` again, not sure what he is actually asking

Comment: Are you sure it gives 5? I expect 10.

Comment: The actual code prints 10. You should close this post and take the time to write a new question by explaining well your problem.

Comment: @sameerasy Oh, I misread that as `5`, `10`, `15`,... In that case it's really unclear what the question is about

Comment: It prints **10** as the output. Are you sure it gives **5**? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbHQzcGI5dDNGLUU

Answer (score 2):

The variable `x` is defined in the scope of the method and therefore will always be newly created, and later be thrown away.

```
public static void test() {
    int x = 5;

    x = x + 5;
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

Put the variable in a greater scope (easiest in this example is to put it before the method):

```
static int x = 5;

public static void test() {
    x = x + 5;
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

BUT:

- Usually methods and fields should not be `static`, unless there is a good reason for it.
- You can shorten `x = x + 5` to `x += 5`
- If your method alters the variable `x` (a side effect of the method), than at least find a good name for the method.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as you intend to, however you should always consider if you *really* need a static variable which can be modified.

```
public class DemoClass {
    // this variable exists only once, all objects of this class share it
    // keep that in mind when creating multiple objects of this class and calling test() on them!
    static int x = 5;

    public static void test() {
        // check if we need to add to or subtract from x
        if (x > 5) {
            x -= 5;
        } else {
            x += 5;
        }

        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```